# Dual and triple non-TB monitors on a Mac Mini late 2012 (Macmini6,2)

Tags: display, mac-mini, thunderbolt

I'm trying to find out if I can connect two 27" Dell S2740L 927M9-IPS-LED monitors to a Macmini6,2. One via HDMI and the other via TB or USB 3.0.

The Mac Mini doesn't have a Mini DP that I can see, but from what I've read it seems like TB can act as one? I have the option of TB daisying through a Drobo 5D. The GPU is integrated Intel HD Graphics 4000.

Could the 2nd monitor be connected via TB >> Mini DP >> {VGA or DVI} adapter?

In time, I'd like to add a Wacom Cintiq 22HD touch (DVI) as a 3rd (and the primary) monitor. I'm a bit confused as to how that could work.

Comment: You are correct about chaining and miniDP just working when plugged into thunderbolt anywhere in the chain (which terminates the chain as you might expect). Also, I have heard that the Wacom are awesome once you get used to them after a short adjustment period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dual yes natively, Triple not without USB adapter one of the displays.

You can look over these two articles:

- [Apple Thunderbolt Adapters: Frequently asked questions (FAQ) - HT5309](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5309)
- [Thunderbolt ports and displays: Frequently asked questions (FAQ) - HT5219](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219)

[Item 23] of the HT5219 article is most relevant[3](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219#23):

> Q23. **How do I connect my Mini DisplayPort monitor or monitor using a Mini DisplayPort adapter to my Thunderbolt-equipped Mac when I have other Thunderbolt devices connected?**
>
> When connecting a Mini DisplayPort display or a display using a Mini DisplayPort adapter to a Thunderbolt peripheral (except as described in question 24), make sure the display is connected at the end of the Thunderbolt chain. You can use only one Mini DisplayPort device in the Thunderbolt chain.
>
> Note: Systems with more than one Thunderbolt port, like an iMac, can have more than one Mini DisplayPort monitor or monitor connected with a Mini DisplayPort adapter connected as each Thunderbolt port can support one Mini DisplayPort display.

[Item #18](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219#18), footnote 4 explains that you only get two monitors with the Late 2012 Mac Mini using Thunderbolt and/or HDMI. To add a third, you'll need a USB adapter for the one that has the fewest pixels / slowest refresh rate requirements. Perhaps you can get a newer (or used but more capable) Mac when it's time to run the Wacom Touch.

> MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012), MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012), and Mac Mini (Late 2012) computers can use an HDMI-compatible device on it's HDMI port while using one Thunderbolt display, or they can use two Thunderbolt displays.

You'll want to use either a thunderbolt to the exact adapter for each monitor rather than chaining two adapters together if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's clearer to me now. I'll hunt for some adapters based on that and hopefully post back here when I have things working. :) I'm indeed thinking about expanding to a Mac Pro at some point, with all these displays being carried over.

Comment: Yes - that puppy can dance. Even the old Mac Pro can now be had for a very good price - new and second hand. You might score one for less than the cost of a second mini by selling your Mini in the process.